# if my app doesn't transmit any sensitive info and I use OAuth/OpenID exclusively for logins, can I get rid of SSL?

Tags: ssl, oauth, openid

I'm rebuilding a site and planning on using OpenID/Oauth (Twitter, Google, Facebook, Yahoo etc) for login. I don't plan on keeping any passwords in my database. This is largely so that users won't need to keep another password and so I won't have to worry about lost passwords in case of a break in.

Since the site doesn't keep anything remotely sensitive (but does require a way to keep users straight) can I just forget about SSL? I'm not seeing any reason for it since no passwords will be traveling over my pages.